# Writing a math equation answer to .txt by using a tkinter widget

Tags: python, math, tkinter, calculation

sorry for the weird code... its the result of 7 hours of trying to get things to work.

I want to capture the quantity, name, price and VAT Incl price in a text file via python & tkinter.

So far I can successfully get the qty, name, price written to text, however, I can not seem to figure out how to take the price, calculate it and write the answer to text.

I have tried bypassing the int vs str problem in multiple ways, including calculating the price and using .insert() to send the answer to Ent5 (entry box) and retrieve the answer with .get() to write it to text, but I get an error code. -->

"TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

I am using .pack() to speed up the testing before going to grid and am aware grid is better.

Here is a small snippit of the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import math

top = tk.Tk()
top.title('Name')
top.geometry('500x450')

v = IntVar()

Ent1 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable=v, show=None, font=('Arial', 16))
Ent2 = tk.Entry(top, show=None, font=('Arial', 16))
Ent3 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable=vT, show=None, font=('Arial', 16))
Ent5 = tk.Entry(top, show=None, font=('Arial', 16)) ###PLACEHOLDER

lbl1 = tk.Label(top, text='Quantity')
lbl2 = tk.Label(top, text='Product')
lbl3 = tk.Label(top, text='Price')

lbl1.pack()
Ent1.pack()
lbl2.pack()
Ent2.pack()
lbl3.pack()
Ent3.pack()
Ent5.pack() ###PLACEHOLDER

int_answers = int(Ent3.get())

def com2():
    km = int_answers*1.15
    Ent5.insert(0, '1.15') ### PLACEHOLDER

def com1():
    com2()
    file1 = open('eca.txt', 'a')
    L = [Ent1.get(), '   |   ' , Ent2.get(), '   |   ' , Ent3.get(), km,'\n']
    file1.writelines(L)
    file1.close()

Btn1 = tk.Button(top, command=com1, text='Ok').pack(side=BOTTOM)

top.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Just to add the ### PLACEHOLDER sections are not in use at all and is just random attempts at different things.

Comment: I cannot get the mentioned error when running your code after fixing the error `name 'vT' is not defined` (in line `Ent3 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable=vT, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error reported but did get a couple of others.

`int_answers = int(Ent3.get())` must be called by the button command function.  I've put it inside `com2`.  In the question int_answers is set to zero before mainloop runs.  Therefore it isn't amended as the Entry is changed.  Moving it to code run after the 'ok' button is clicked means the Entry is read after it's been changed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import math

top = tk.Tk()
top.title('Name')
top.geometry('500x450')

v = IntVar()
vT = IntVar() # Missing in the question.

Ent1 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable=v, show=None, font=('Arial', 16))
Ent2 = tk.Entry(top, show=None, font=('Arial', 16))
Ent3 = tk.Entry(top, textvariable=vT, show=None, font=('Arial', 16))

lbl1 = tk.Label(top, text='Quantity')
lbl2 = tk.Label(top, text='Product')
lbl3 = tk.Label(top, text='Price')

result = tk.Label( top, text = '0') # See the result in the GUI

lbl1.pack()
Ent1.pack()
lbl2.pack()
Ent2.pack()
lbl3.pack()
Ent3.pack()
result.pack()

# int_answers = int(Ent3.get())
# Move inside the com2 function

def com2():
    int_answers = int(Ent3.get())
    km = int_answers*1.15
    result.config( text = str(km)) # Show the result in the GUI
    return km   # Return the result to com1.

def com1():
    km = com2() # Otherwise com1 can't 'see' km
    file1 = open('eca.txt', 'a')
    L = [Ent1.get(), '   |   ' , Ent2.get(), '   |   ' , Ent3.get(), str(km),'\n']
    file1.writelines(L)
    print(L) # Seewhat's happening in the console.
    file1.close()

Btn1 = tk.Button(top, command=com1, text='Ok').pack(side=BOTTOM)

top.mainloop()
```

One other point.  I'd use a more robust `to_int` conversion.  It will return zero if the string can't convert to int rather than raise an exception.

```
def to_int( string):
    try: 
        return int(string)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. I was wondering how to do a proper conversion to int, this helped me a lot! :D appreciate it man